# Why am I getting `fatal: not a git repository...` when looking up toplevel dir in a git worktree?

Tags: git, docker, git-worktree

I'm currently tinkering with git worktrees and suddenly ran into a problem. I tried both approaches with and without bare clones described here:

https://infrequently.org/2021/07/worktrees-step-by-step/
and
https://svij.org/blog/2017/04/14/mit-git-worktree-mehrere-arbeitsverzeichnisse-managen/ (ger)

and my current directory setup looks like this:

```
$ tree -aL 1
.
├── worktree-branch1
├── worktree-master
└── .git
```

when I'm entering e.g. `worktree-master` and run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` using git version `2.17.1` it points me correctly to the worktree root.

When I now do the same inside a Docker-container based on `ubuntu:20.04` running version `2.25.1` of git I'm getting

```
$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
fatal: not a git repository: /home/me/git-project/.git/worktrees/worktree-master
```

Is this an issue with this specific version? Or does git make use of some strange magic which does not work inside a Docker container?

Is there a workaround for this to get the worktrees toplevel dir?

Comment: This is, as you discovered, actually a Docker setup problem: for this directory layout to work, you must have the *same* (relative) directory layout inside your container.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.

Problem was, I'm running the container using something like

```
REPO_DIR="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
docker run -it --rm -v "$(REPO_DIR):$(REPO_DIR)" ubuntu:20.04 bash
```

inside the worktree, which worked without worktrees, since all git needs was located inside `./.git`.

Now - with the worktree - git tries to access `../.git` which was not available given the command I posted.

The optimization I need now would be to get the parent directory both the worktree and the bare clone share (which usually should be a parent directory of `REPO_DIR`).